# What are the possible returns of a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, types, return

I wonder what would be the possible **returns** of a given **function** in *JavaScript*.

Someone has a list of the possibilities?

I guess the possibilites are around the diferent types of a variable, that I know as this types:

- undefined;
- null;
- boolean;
- number;
- string;
- object.

Comment: Anything. Any of the JS primitives, null, object, function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: ...also `functions`,`symbols`

Comment: Any value can be returned.

Comment: There's nothing you cannot return.

Answer (score -1):

Return types in any programming language, including Javascript, can be determined by the list of types it support. You can of course combine a lot of these like:

- An array of booleans
- An object that has array value
- An array of objects/array

You can see the list of datatypes in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). But pretty much you have six primitive types:

- undefined
- Boolean
- Number
- String
- BigInt
- Symbol

And:

- null
- and finally object. Arrays, Set, Date are all objects. What that means is that, for example, an array is just a special type of object with key/value pairs and you can access these properties by doing e.g. array.length.

Function is another type of special object.